# How do i use two versions of passenger on the same server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, ubuntu, passenger

Ok so i just launched a ubuntu instance that I installed rvm and passenger to launch my rails application ..the problem is that I now need to have two applications and 1 needs ruby 1.9.2 and one needs ruby 1.8.7

This is fine because I can create a new gemset based on the two rubies but the problem is passenger

my apache2.conf contains this

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/passenger-3.0.11
PassengerRuby /home/ubuntu/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ruby
```

and as you can see it is using the passenger from ruby-1.9.2> my question is how do i for another site on the same server do i use the passenger for 1.8.7

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because these two directives (`PassengerRoot`, `PassengerRuby`) are global

[The doc](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengerroot_lt_directory_gt) says "This required option may only occur once, in the global server configuration."

I personnally deploy with **Thin+mod_proxy** or **FastCGI via mod_fcgid**. Both are very reasonable to setup, and allow any number of different worlds (Ruby/Rails/whatever version combination) side by side. How to do it is another thread I guess.